# C++ Download File WinInet - 0kb written to file

Tags: c++, winapi, wininet

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code?

I am trying to download a file from the internet using WinInet. The function connects to the target site just fine, I don't understand why this code isn't working. Can anyone help me out?

Here is my code:

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFileW(FilePath, GENERIC_WRITE, NULL, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, NULL, NULL);
if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE || GetLastError() == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS)
{
  CHAR Buffer[2048];
  DWORD BytesRead=0, BytesToRead=0;
  DWORD BytesWritten=0, BytesToWrite=0;
  SetFilePointer(hFile, 0, 0, FILE_BEGIN);
  do
  {
    if (BytesRead)
    {
      WriteFile(hFile, Buffer, BytesWritten, &BytesToWrite, FALSE);
    }
  }
  while
  (InternetReadFile(hRequest, (LPVOID)Buffer, BytesToRead, &BytesRead) != FALSE);
}
CloseHandle(hFile);
}
```

hRequest is passed to the function, it is the HINTERNET handle from HttpOpenRequestA.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WinINet trouble downloading file to client?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539951/wininet-trouble-downloading-file-to-client)

Comment: You never set `BytesWritten` to anything other than `0` (and as an aside, you have the names of `BytesWritten` and `BytesToWrite` swapped around in the `WriteFile` call).

Comment: But aside from that, the rest of the code looks good?

Comment: If you fix that it should write data at least :)

Comment: Your first `if`-clause doesn't make sense. If the last error code is set to `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`, you'll potentially wind up writing to a file identified by the handle `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`, i.e. you're not writing anything.

Answer (score 3):

Your code has some logic problems.

1. you are misusing `GetLastError()` when calling `CreateFileW()`.  Regardless of whether the file already exists or not, `CreateFileW()` will not return `INVALID_HANDLE` if it successfully creates/opens the file.  That is all you need to check for (call `GetLastError()` only if `CreateFileW()` fails and you want to find out why).  also, there is no need to call `SetFilePointer()` at all, as `CREATE_ALWAYS` ensures the opened file is empty, truncating the file if it already exists and has data in it.
2. your `do..while` loop should be a `while` loop instead, so that `InternetReadFile()` is called first.  There is no point in skipping `WriteFile()` on the first loop iteration.  If you use a `do..while` loop, `InternetReadFile()` should not be used as the loop condition.
3. more importantly, you are breaking the loop *only* if `InternetReadFile()` fails with an error.  You are expecting it to fail when it reaches the end of the response, but it actually returns TRUE and sets `BytesRead` to 0.  This is documented behavior, which you are not handling at all:

   [InternetReadFile function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385103.aspx)

   > **InternetReadFile operates much like the base ReadFile function**, with a few exceptions. Typically, InternetReadFile retrieves data from an HINTERNET handle as a sequential stream of bytes. The amount of data to be read for each call to InternetReadFile is specified by the dwNumberOfBytesToRead parameter and the data is returned in the lpBuffer parameter. A normal read retrieves the specified dwNumberOfBytesToRead for each call to InternetReadFile until the end of the file is reached. **To ensure all data is retrieved, an application must continue to call the InternetReadFile function until the function returns TRUE and the lpdwNumberOfBytesRead parameter equals zero**. This is especially important if the requested data is written to the cache, because otherwise the cache will not be properly updated and the file downloaded will not be committed to the cache. Note that caching happens automatically unless the original request to open the data stream set the INTERNET_FLAG_NO_CACHE_WRITE flag.

   [ReadFile function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467.aspx)

   > When a synchronous read operation reaches the end of a file, **ReadFile returns TRUE and sets *lpNumberOfBytesRead to zero**.
4. when calling `WriteFile()`, you are passing `BytesWritten` to the `nNumberOfBytesToWrite` parameter, but `BytesWritten` is never set to anything other than 0, so nothing gets written to the file.  You need to pass `BytesRead` instead.

With that said, use something more like this:

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFileW(FilePath, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN, NULL);
if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    // handle error as needed...
}
else
{
    BYTE Buffer[2048];
    DWORD BytesRead, BytesWritten;

    do
    {
        if (!InternetReadFile(hRequest, Buffer, sizeof(Buffer), &BytesRead))
        {
            // handle error as needed...
            break;
        }

        if (!BytesRead)
            break;

        if (!WriteFile(hFile, Buffer, BytesRead, &BytesWritten, FALSE))
        {
            // handle error as needed...
            break;
        }
    }
    while (true);

    CloseHandle(hFile);
}
```

MSDN even has a full example of how to use `InternetReadFile()`:

[HOWTO: Using InternetReadFile To Get File](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/149413)

```
BOOL GetFile (HINTERNET IN hOpen, // Handle from InternetOpen()
              CHAR *szUrl,        // Full URL
              CHAR *szFileName)   // Local file name
{
   DWORD dwSize;
   CHAR   szHead[] = "Accept: */*\r\n\r\n";
   VOID * szTemp[25];
   HINTERNET  hConnect;
   FILE * pFile;

   if ( !(hConnect = InternetOpenUrl ( hOpen, szUrl, szHead,
         lstrlen (szHead), INTERNET_FLAG_DONT_CACHE, 0)))
   {
      cerr << "Error !" << endl;
      return 0;
   }

   if  ( !(pFile = fopen (szFileName, "wb" ) ) )
   {
      cerr << "Error !" << endl;
      return FALSE;
   }
   do
   {
      // Keep coping in 25 bytes chunks, while file has any data left.
      // Note: bigger buffer will greatly improve performance.
      if (!InternetReadFile (hConnect, szTemp, 50,  &dwSize) )
      {
         fclose (pFile);
         cerr << "Error !" << endl;
         return FALSE;
      }
      if (!dwSize)
         break;  // Condition of dwSize=0 indicate EOF. Stop.
      else
         fwrite(szTemp, sizeof (char), dwSize , pFile);
   }   // do
   while (TRUE);
   fflush (pFile);
   fclose (pFile);
   return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: You obviously have too much free time on your hands ;)

Comment: I don't get MSDN's example. What is `void* szTemp[25]`? Pointer to array of bytes? It's not allocated then it reads 50 bytes in this call `InternetReadFile (hConnect, szTemp, 50,  &dwSize)` They seem to do it deliberately, they even comment about it.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: Good catch. In MSDN's first example, `VOID* szTemp[25];` needs to be `BYTE szTemp]50];` instead, and in their second example, `TCHAR sz[1024];` needs to be `BYTE sz[1024];` instead. I have submitted those changes to Microsoft.