# Writing stdin to a file

Tags: c, stream, pipe, stdin

I'm trying to write stdin to a file, but for some reason, I keed reading zero bytes.

Here's my source:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 1024

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    if (feof(stdin))
        printf("stdin reached eof\n");

    void *content = malloc(BUF_SIZE);

    FILE *fp = fopen("/tmp/mimail", "w");

    if (fp == 0)
        printf("...something went wrong opening file...\n");

    printf("About to write\n");
    int read;
    while ((read = fread(content, BUF_SIZE, 1, stdin))) {
        printf("Read %d bytes", read);
        fwrite(content, read, 1, fp);
        printf("Writing %d\n", read);
    }
    if (ferror(stdin))
        printf("There was an error reading from stdin");

    printf("Done writing\n");

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm running `cat test.c | ./test` and the output is just

```
About to write
Done writing
```

It seems zero bytes are read, even though I'm piping lots of stuff.

Comment: Hi - The problem is the way you're using "read".  Check out this link for correct usage - and a solution: [Read from stdin write to stdout in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10129085/read-from-stdin-write-to-stdout-in-c)

Comment: The answer below is correct but there are some style (or otherwise somewhat minor) issues.   One is that you can just declare `content` as a char array.  No need to `malloc` it.  Second, `fread` returns `size_t`, not `int`, so your variable `read` has a different type.   You should also rename it on order to avoid using the same name as a global function (`read` is a global function, in fact a system call).  Your code closes `fp` without checking for failure.   It also reads stdin even if `/tmp/mimail' could not be opened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got the two integer arguments to `fread()` reversed. You're telling it to fill the buffer once, or fail. Instead, you want to tell it to read single characters, up to 1024 times. Reverse the two integer arguments, and it'll work as designed.

Comment: It's instructive to add a long comment to the source to make it longer than BUF_SIZE.  Then the `while` loop gets entered once.

Comment: @gcbenison Using test.c as an input was just a test; it really does need to read any sort of data from stdin.

Comment: @ernest-friedman-hill Thanks, my bad, I hadn't payed much attention to that.  I'll keep en eye out for this sort of thing in future:)