# fread() return value in C

Tags: c

I am trying to understand how the `fread()` function in `<stdio.h>` works and I am confused about the return value of this function.  In the man pages it says

> RETURN VALUE
>          On  success, `fread()`  and `fwrite()` return the number of items read
>          or written.  This number equals the number of bytes transferred only
>          when size is 1.  If an error occurs, or the end of the file is
>          reached, the return value is a short item count (or zero).
>
> `fread()` does not distinguish between end-of-file and error, and 
>          callers must use `feof(3)` and `ferror(3)` to determine which occurred.

Could someone please explain to me what is meant by `number of items read or written` in this context.  Also can anyone provide me with some example return values and their meanings?

Comment: `fread()` reads `N * K` bytes, where `N` is the number of bytes in each element, and in total `K` elements will be read. Ideally, if no error occurs, `K` will be returned. If an error or end-of-file condition occurs, then less than `K` elements may be read, in which case a number smaller than `K` will be returned.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8589425/827263

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`fread()` will read a *count* of items of a specified *size* from the provided IO stream (`FILE* stream`). It returns the *number of items successfully read* from the stream. If it returns a number less than the requested number of items, the IO stream can be considered empty (or otherwise broken).

The number of bytes read will be equal to the *number of items successfully read* times the provided *size* of the items.

Consider the following program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char buf[8];
    size_t ret = fread(buf, sizeof(*buf), sizeof(buf)/sizeof(*buf), stdin);
    printf("read %zu bytes\n", ret*sizeof(*buf));
    return 0;
}
```

When we run this program, depending on the amount of input provided, different outcomes can be observed.

We can provide no input at all. The IO stream will be empty to begin with (EOF). The return value will be zero. No items have been read. Zero is returned.

```
$ : | ./a.out
read 0 bytes
```

We provide fewer input as requested. Some items will be read before EOF is encountered. The number of items read is returned. No more items are available. Thereafter the stream is empty.

```
$ echo "Hello" | ./a.out
read 6 bytes
```

We provide equal or more input as requested. The number of items as requested will be returned. More items may be available.

```
$ echo "Hello World" | ./a.out
read 8 bytes
```

Related reading:

- [What is the rationale for fread/fwrite taking size and count as arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/295994/1025391)

When there are less bytes in the stream than consitute an item, the number of bytes *consumed* from the stream might however be greater than the number of bytes *read* as calculated by above formula. This answer to above linked question (and the comment to it) I find especially insightful in this matter:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/296305/1025391

Comment: Your program would be more helpful (regarding the question) if it did a fread() of a file being 7 bytes long and the size set to 1, 2 and 4.

Answer (score 7):

The syntax for `fread()` is

```
size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE * stream );
```

which means,

> The function `fread()` reads **`nmemb` elements of data, each `size` bytes long,** from the stream pointed to by `stream`, storing them at the location given by `ptr`.

So, the total number of bytes read will be `nmemb * size`.

Now, by saying

> on success, fread() and fwrite() return the number of items read or written. This number equals the number of bytes transferred only when size is 1.

it means that, the return value will equal the `nmemb` when the `size` is `1.`

Logic is same, in case of `fwrite()` also.

---

EDIT

for example, a fully successful call to `fread()` like

```
 fread(readbuf, sizeof(int), 5 , stdin);
```

will return `5` while it will read `sizeof(int) * 5` bytes. If we assume `sizeof(int)` is `4`, then total bytes read will be `5 * 4` or `20`. As you can see, here, *the number of items read or written* is **not equal** to the *number of bytes transferred*.

OTOH, another fully successful call to `fread()` like

```
fread(readbuf, sizeof(char), 5 , stdin);
```

will also return `5` while it will read `sizeof(char) * 5` bytes, i.e., `5` bytes. In this case, as `sizeof(char)` is `1`, so, here, *the number of items read or written* is **equal** to the *number of bytes transferred*. i.e., `5`.

Comment: what happens when size != 1 though?  I'm reading through code that passes the size of a struct to this function.