# What is this implementation of fread in Chromium OS made of?

Tags: c, libc

I was looking at the **[source code of fread in chromium-os / glibc](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/third_party/glibc/+/cvs/libc-960824/stdio/fread.c)** and became increasingly puzzled about it.

**NB: I am talking about the source code and NOT the use of [fread](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fread.3.html) or [other related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295994/what-is-the-rationale-for-fread-fwrite-taking-size-and-count-as-arguments)**

---

#### Function prototype as a macro

First I was surprised about the way that fread is declared as a macro with its function name, followed by its arguments and finally its arguments' type:

```c
/* Read NMEMB chunks of SIZE bytes each from STREAM into P.  */

size_t
DEFUN(fread, (p, size, nmemb, stream),
      PTR p AND size_t size AND size_t nmemb AND register FILE *stream)
```

*What is the rationale behind this and why not*

```c
size_t fread(PTR p, size_t size, size_t nmemb, register FILE * stream)
```

*which is much more readable?*

---

#### What is __fillbf(register FILE *stream)

I was especially puzzled about this line:

```c
int c = __fillbf(stream);
```

and could not find this function anywhere. I thought that it could be a system call that I don't already know about but it is not part of [the table](https://filippo.io/linux-syscall-table/)

**So what is the real code behind `__fill_bf(register FILE *)` ?**

Edit: Thanks to **dyp** for macro definition, **Crowman** for `__fillbf` and **Ray** for the nice synthesis of explanation!

*ps: any answer with some extra explanations about the tricky parts of fread are also welcome!*

Comment: Where did you get the source code?

Comment: chromium, its in the hyperlink, sorry I removed the ` ` to make it more apparent

Comment: Regarding DEFUN: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/third_party/glibc/+/cvs/libc-960824/ansidecl.h *"It becomes a prototype in ANSI C, and the type declarations in traditional C.*"

Comment: *So what is the real code behind __fill_bf(register FILE *)* - I would say it is a builtin function. Maybe you better ask *what does it do*?

Comment: I already have a guess on what it does... we are using fread ;)

Comment: I think glibc code will not contain syscalls directly except in architecture-specific folders. Also, there's probably some non-underscored `fillbf` somewhere.

Comment: `__fillbf` is defined starting line 591 of `internals.c`

Comment: why don't you look at the normal glibc instead of chromium's version?

Comment: I googled it and thought that chromium would use the exact same version

Comment: @Crowman Thanks!! Where can I find the source code of internals.c?

Comment: note that `__fillbf()` has no chance to be a system call since `FILE *` concerns only userland/libc.

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL It is in the same source directory as `fgets.c` is - the one you linked

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL: In the same link from your question - just click up a level in the breadcrumbs at the very top of the page.

Comment: @prog-fh when I am desperately looking for an answer I am not always rational

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## DEFUN

Before ANSI-standardization, function declaration had a different syntax:

ANSI-declaration:

```
int f(int x, double y) {
...
}
```

Pre-ANSI (K&R1) declaration:

```
f(x, y)
int x;
double y;
{
...
}
```

Macros like `DEFUN` are often defined for programs that may need to be compiled by very old compilers. (It's less common now, since ANSI standardization happened back in 1989.)  There will be a file that defines macros one way if using ANSI/ISO C, and another way if using pre-ANSI C. (For chromiumos, that would be [ansidecl.h](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/third_party/glibc/+/d705269e75ff9846000abea981774b381b076482/ansidecl.h).) DEFUN calls will thus expand into the appropriate decl format for the compiler being used.

## __fillbf

As Crowman mentioned in the comments, the definition for `__fillbf` is in [internals.c](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/third_party/glibc/+/cvs/libc-970720/stdio/internals.c).  It appears that it reads a block of characters into an internal buffer, so that `fgetc` can read one character at a time without needing to make a disk access each time.